# Building Cloud from Scratch using Openstack

Tags: cloud, openstack, owncloud

I would like to build a private cloud for my project. I need to build the cloud from scratch - not like own-cloud or xapi where the cloud is ready to use
How can I start building one and what are the steps?!
Can I use OpenStack ?
If so can anyone help me with the steps?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create your own private cloud using openstack.

As for the steps;

http://docs.openstack.org/juno/install-guide/install/apt/content/

Other options are devstack (for development / Proof of concept - Not Production!) or RDO from redhat or one of the other commercial vendors involved in openstack (dell / ibm etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the recent documentation for Mitaka on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:
http://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-ubuntu/

"This guide will walk through an installation by using packages available through Canonical’s Ubuntu Cloud archive repository.

Explanations of configuration options and sample configuration files are included.

This guide documents OpenStack Mitaka release."

Comment: Would be a good idea to include a relevant excerpt from the link, in the body of your answer.